# qTip2: how to display a tooltip within a tooltip?

Tags: javascript, qtip2

I am using qTip2 to display a text box, within which there is a link. I want to display a tooltip when mouse is over this link.

Cannot figure out how to do this.

First, is this doable? And then how if yes?

Thanks for help!

### Edit

Dihedral, thanks so much for your info. I followed your approach, but it is still not working. I looked at the html code of the page and notice that in your jsFiddle code, additional html is generated (by qTip) for the second tooltip popup. But in my case, I cannot find such additional html.

The following is my code and this is the jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/bacqe/6/

```
    $('#author').qtip({
    content: {
        text: $('#author-container').html()
    },
    show: {
  solo: false,
        event: 'mouseover'
    },      
    hide: {
        event: 'unfocus'
    },
    style: {
        tip: false,
        classes: 'author-content forcedzLowIndex'
    },      
    position: {
        my: 'top right',
        at: 'bottom right'
    },
    events: {
        render: function() {
            buildQtipInfoTooltip($('#author-allow-friends-link'), 'title', 'forcedzHighIndex');
        }
    }
}); 

function buildQtipInfoTooltip(jEle, attr_name, classes) {
    jEle.qtip({
        content: jEle.attr(attr_name),
        position: {
            at: 'bottom right',
            viewport: $(window),
            adjust: {
                y: 4,
                x: 0,
                method: 'shift'
            }
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'tooltip' + ' ' + classes,
            tip: false
        }
    }); 
}   

.forcedzLowIndex {
    z-index: 10000 !important;
}

.forcedzHighIndex {
    z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying my answer to use your example code:

Your first qTip uses

```
content: {
    text: $('#author-container').html()
},
```

for the content. That technique will result in a clone of the #author-container elements, instead of using the existing elements. So your second qTip was being applied, but it was getting applied to elements that were never appearing on screen.

I took away the .html() and it worked for me. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/bacqe/13/

```
content: {
    text: $('#author-container')
},
```

Comment: Dihedral, thanks so much for your info. I followed your approach, but it is still not working. I looked at the html code and notice that in your jsFiddle code, additional html is generated for the second tooltip popup. But in my case, I cannot find such additional html...weird.

Comment: What is the additional HTML?
Are you able to create a jsFiddle showing the problem?

Comment: I added my code in the above. The additional HTML is hidden divs qTip generated.

Comment: Made updates to my answer given your code. Also, you may end up not needing the zIndex forcing. I'd suggest playing around with different options there.

Comment: Dihedral, thanks so much for pointing out the issue with html(). You are really the best!!!